# Offset and fetch in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have data in millions (total rows 1698393). While exporting this data in text takes 4 hours. I need to know if there is a way to reduce the exporting time for those many records from Oracle database using SQL Developer.

```
with cte as (
  select *
  from (
   select distinct
          system_serial_number,
          ( select s.system_status
            from   eim_pr_system s
            where  .system_serial_number=a.system_serial_number
          ) system_status,
          ( select SN.cmat_customer_id
            from   EIM.eim_pr_ib_latest SN
            where  SN.role_id=19
            and    SN.system_serial_number=a.system_serial_number
          ) SN_cmat_customer_id,
          ( select  EC.cmat_customer_id
            from EIM.eim_pr_ib_latest EC
            where EC.role_id=1
            and   a.system_serial_number=EC.system_serial_number
          ) EC_cmat_customer_id
    from  EIM.eim_pr_ib_latest a
    where a.role_id in (1,19)
  ) 
  where nvl(SN_cmat_customer_id,0)!=nvl(EC_cmat_customer_id,0)
)
select system_serial_number,
       system_status,
       SN_CMAT_Customer_ID,
       EC_CMAT_Customer_ID,
       C.Customer_Name SN_Customer_Name,
       D.Customer_Name EC_Customer_Name
from   cte,
       eim.eim_party c,
       eim.eim_party D
where  c.CMAT_Customer_ID=SN_cmat_customer_id
and    D.CMAT_Customer_ID=EC_cmat_customer_id;
offset first 5001 rows fetch next 200000 rows only
```

Comment: sample data for testing... its an output of the original query

Comment: SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER SYSTEM_STATUS SN_CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID EC_CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID SN_CUSTOMER_NAME EC_CUSTOMER_NAME
0000299DF0053 ACTIVE -999999 5016269  NetApp Inc.
100092756 INACTIVE 5019768 -999999 S&T System Integration & Technology Distribution AG 
100007122 DECOMISSIONED 5007419 6062535 Hartford Life Orix Life Insurance Corp.
100007127 DECOMISSIONED 5016269 -999999 NetApp Inc. 
1000511 DECOMISSIONED 6004941 -999999 Strato Rechenzentrum AG 
100653517 ACTIVE 5008192 5015642 General Dynamics Corp. Maryland Procurement Office

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of a lot of the joins and correlated sub-queries (which will speed things up by reducing the number of table scans) by doing something like:

```
SELECT a.system_serial_number,
       s.system_status,
       a.SN_cmat_customer_id,
       a.EC_cmat_customer_id,
       a.SN_customer_name,
       a.EC_customer_name
FROM   (
  SELECT l.system_serial_number,
         MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN 19 THEN l.cmat_customer_id END ) AS SN_cmat_customer_id,
         MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN  1 THEN l.cmat_customer_id END ) AS EC_cmat_customer_id
         MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN 19 THEN p.customer_name END ) AS SN_customer_name,
         MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN  1 THEN p.customer_name END ) AS EC_customer_name
  FROM   EIM.eim_pr_ib_latest l
         INNER JOIN
         EIM.eim_aprty p
         ON ( p.CMAT_Customer_ID= l.cmat_customer_id )
  WHERE  l.role_id IN ( 1, 19 )
  GROUP BY system_serial_number
  HAVING    NVL( MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN 19 THEN l.cmat_customer_id END ), 0 )
         <> NVL( MAX( CASE l.role_id WHEN  1 THEN l.cmat_customer_id END ), 0 )
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
eim_pr_system s
ON ( s.system_serial_number=a.system_serial_number )
```

Since your original query is not throwing a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` exception on the correlated sub-queries, I am assuming that your data is such that there is only a single row being returned for each correlated query and the above query will reflect your output (although without some sample data it is difficult to test).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from 'making the query faster' - there is a way to achieve a faster export using SQL Developer.

When you use the data grid, export feature - this will execute the query, again. The only time this won't happen is if you have fetched ALL the rows into the grid. Doing this will for very large data sets will be 'expensive' on the client side, but you can avoid that.

For a faster export, add a `/*csv*/` comment in your select, and wrap the statement with a spool c:\my_file.csv - then collapse the script output panel, and run that with F5. As we fetch the data, we'll write it to that file in a CSV format.

```
/*csv*/
/*xml*/
/*json*/
/*html*/
/*insert*/
```

I talk about this feature in detail [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/).